# Setting global var from within snapshot

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set currentUser variable from within the snapshot from firestore:

```
var currentUser: CurrentUser!
func Login(){
  let db = Firestore.firestore()
                let userRef = db.collection("users")
                var u: CurrentUser!

                userRef.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    if let err = error{
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                    }else{
                        print("FOUND")
                        for document in snapshot!.documents{
                            u = CurrentUser(data: document.data())
                            print(u.username)
                          self.currentUser = u
                           print(self.currentUser.username)
                        }
                    }
                }

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SEGUE_LOGGED_IN", sender: self)
            }}
```

self.currentUser.username is always nil. Something to do with asynchronous call Im not sure. If someone can help me set the currentUser variable from within the snapshot block would be great. I am new to Swift.

Comment: Your global variable is called `currentUser`, but you are assigning the instance to a variable called `current`. Are there multiple variables and you picked the wrong one?

Comment: Sorry edited my question to make sure they are all currentUser. Still doesnt work